# How to pass additional data to the action function in react router dom v6.4

Tags: react-router-dom

```
<Route
  action={async ({ request, params }) => {
    let formData = await request.formData();
    // ...
  }}
/>
```

as shown above the action function can only get data from request and params. Is there any other way to get an additional information while submitting the form.

I tried to put the additional information in the search params using the action props in the form like this `action="submit.php?additional_data=some%20additional%20data"` and try to access search params in the action function. But I couln't access the location object in the action function.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with hidden inputs

```
<input name='hiddenInput1' readOnly hidden value={additionalData}
```